# Red bar after if conditional. (python)

Tags: python, syntax-error

In a simple program I was writing in python for experimenting with the language. My program refused to run and said there was a syntax error even though I checked it several times.

I'm currently a beginner at coding so I'm sort of pathetic when it comes to almost everything, including trying to find an answer because most of the jargons are also very new to me.

The error occurred after the if var == 2 and was shown with a red blank bar.

```
var = 2
if var == 2
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: Missing a `:` after 2

Comment: run through some tutorials, you'll learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a colon after the if statement.